# crm 2011 ribbon: disable system button

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I have a problem with disabling ribbon button via javascript custom rule.

The action for that I want to add "enable rule" is called Mscrm.AddExistingRecordFromSubGridAssociated -> which is displayed when subgrid gets focus.

I use the ribbon workbench solution and I almost sure I did everything fine, but it doesn't work.

javascript:

```
utils.ribbon.isAddExistingDisabled = function(grid) {
 return false; //just for test I wrote always false, but it's enabled anyway :/
}
```

CommandDef:

```
<CommandDefinition Id="Mscrm.AddExistingRecordFromSubGridAssociated">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.AppendToPrimary" />
        <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.EntityFormIsEnabled" />
        <EnableRule Id="my.incident.addMainCause.EnableRule" />
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AddExisting" />
        <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.ShowForManyToManyGrids" />
        <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AppendToPrimary" />
        <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AppendSelected" />
      </DisplayRules>
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridAssociated" Library="/_static/_common/scripts/RibbonActions.js">
          <CrmParameter Value="SelectedEntityTypeCode" />
          <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControl" />
        </JavaScriptFunction>
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>
```

Enable rule def:

```
<EnableRule Id="my.incident.addMainCause.EnableRule">
        <CustomRule FunctionName="utils.ribbon.isAddExistingDisabled" Library="$webresource:my_js/incident/common.js" InvertResult="false">
          <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControl" />
        </CustomRule>
      </EnableRule>
```

Comment: why do you have <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControl" /> within your CustomRule?

Comment: I wanted to pass SelectedControl as a parameter to javascript function, because depened on that, I want to hide/show the "Add Existing {0}" button